# Initializing static global constants with enum value. Is this safe? Pitfalls?

Tags: c++, static, enums, initialization

If you want to wrap some enum type with a class, e.g., to build some functions around it, you could end up with the following situation:

main.cpp:

```
#include "WrappedEnumConstants.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   WrappedZero.print();
   WrappedOne.print();
}
```

WrappedEnumConstants.h

```
#ifndef WRAPEDENUMCONSTANTS_H
#define WRAPEDENUMCONSTANTS_H

#include "WrappedEnum.h"
#include "InternalEnum.h"

static const WrappedEnum WrappedZero(ZeroEnum);
static const WrappedEnum WrappedOne(OneEnum);

#endif
```

WrappedEnum.h

```
#ifndef WRAPPEDENUM_H
#define WRAPPEDENUM_H

#include <iostream>
#include "InternalEnum.h"

class WrappedEnum
{
public:
   WrappedEnum(InternalEnum a);
   void print() const;
private:
   InternalEnum a;
};
#endif
```

WrappedEnum.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WrappedEnum.h"

WrappedEnum::WrappedEnum(InternalEnum a) :
   a(a)
{}

void WrappedEnum::print() const {
   std::cout << "WrappedEnum: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

InternalEnum.h

```
#ifndef INTERNALENUM_H
#define INTERNALENUM_H
   enum InternalEnum { ZeroEnum, OneEnum};
#endif
```

The output I get is like expected:

```
WrappedEnum: 0
WrappedEnum: 1
```

I am wondering if initialization of the static constants WrappedZero and WrappedOne is safe. Are the constants of ZeroEnum and OneEnum guaranteed to be initialized before WrappedZero and WrappedOne or was I only lucky? Especially, I am wondering what pitfalls there might be if you used the WrappedEnum in a large project with many things linked together. Do you see any?

Are there differences in initialization of enum constants (like ZeroEnum and OneEnum) and a global "static const int"?

Answer (score 1):

> Are the constants of ZeroEnum and OneEnum guaranteed to be initialized before WrappedZero and WrappedOne or was I only lucky?

They are compile-time constants, so are not initialised at runtime at all. It's safe to use them at any time.

> Are there differences in initialization of enum constants (like ZeroEnum and OneEnum) and a global "static const int"?

If the `static const int` is initialised with a constant value, it will be a compile-time constant in any code that knows its value. Otherwise, it will be initialised during the *static initialisation* phase, before the program starts. In either case, it's also safe to use it at any time.

If it needs to be initialised with a run-time value, then it will be initialised during the *dynamic initialisation* phase (like your "wrapped" objects), and you may encounter problems with the initialisation order.

Comment: Those static-duration instances are not safe to use in general in the initialization of other static-duration instances.

Comment: A `const int` (`static` is irrelevant here) can be initialized with an expression that isn't known at compile time, in which case, it may be subject to dynamic initialization.

Comment: @6502 All static initialization is guaranteed to be done before any dynamic initialization, so variables which are statically initialized cannot cause an order of initialization problem.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Are you sure that `WrappedZero(ZeroEnum)` is a static initialization?

Comment: @6502: It isn't, and James didn't say that. The wrapped objects are dynamically initialised, since they have user-declared constructors. The question is about whether `ZeroEnum` is guaranteed to have the right value at that point.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: therefore you cannot safely use `WrappedZero` during the initialization of another static duration object.

Comment: @6502: Indeed not (at least, not a static object defined in a different translation unit). But that's got nothing to do with the question of whether you can use `ZeroEnum` to initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference.

A field of enum type in an instance is for the compiler unknown at compile time so when generating code it's forced to actually access the instance to find the value and the generated code will be bigger and slower.

A `const int` **can** instead be known at compile time (if you initialize it with a constant) and so the compiler can generate code that uses directly the value (and you can also use that as a constant expression for example in array declarations or templates).

Also note that wrapping your values in static-duration instances you're creating problems for who will use those wrapped values during the initialization of other static duration instances because the order of initialization is not guaranteed.

I'm not really sure why you think it's a good idea to wrap a box that contains what you need in a bag. Except writing a lot more code and annoying the compiler and your users, what good thing are you achieving doing that?

Comment: An `int const` is _not_ necessarily known at compile time.  A definition like `extern int const i;` is perfectly legal, as is `int i = f();`.  (Of course, such `int const` cannot participate in integral constant expressions.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, i meant a const just initialized to a constant like seems the OP is looking for.